# Need to catch clicked image as base64 in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Trying on a web page. I am using PWA, Ionic 4 and Android.

In my `home.html` I have added a button

```
  <!-- Trigger the file input -->
  <ion-button expand="full" (click)="captureImage()">
    <ion-icon slot="start" name="camera"></ion-icon>
    Capture Image
  </ion-button>
```

on my `home.ts` I have this code below:

```
captureImage() {
  this.fileinput.nativeElement.click();
}
```

On clicking the button, it open the option to select `camera app`, now when I select the camera app, it allows me to click image. After clicking it takes me back to screen. Here I want to fetch the image as `base64`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Hi user2828442. Jut a quick reminder that quote blocks (using the > device) are only for quotes, and are not a general highlighter

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the files from :**

`this.fileinput.nativeElement.files;`

For converting the files after selection, use `FileReader.readAsDataUrl()`.
You can find the full code for the same here:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-pwa-camera/151148/12

**To store file:**
Call this before uploading:

```
upload()
{
const fileList: FileList = this. fileinput.nativeElement.files;

    if (fileList && fileList.length > 0) 
    {
      this.firstFileToBase64(fileList[0]).then((result: string) => 
      {
        this.base64File = result;
      }, (err: any) => {
        // Ignore error, do nothing
        this.base64File = null;
      });
    }
  }

  private firstFileToBase64(fileImage: File): Promise<{}> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      if (fileReader && fileImage != null) {
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileImage);
        fileReader.onload = () => {
          resolve(fileReader.result);
        };

        fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
          reject(error);
        };
      } else {
        reject(new Error('No file found'));
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: i only need base 64 value of the clicked image, can you please update my code so that i can get the value in a variable

Comment: hii, i am about to test this, are you online at the moment if i am stuck somewhere ?